# Is there a way to improve speed of parsing date for large file?

Tags: python, performance, cython

I am reading a big csv file which has about 1B rows. I ran into a issue with parsing the date. Python is slow in the processing.

a single line in the file looks like the following,
    `'20170427,20:52:01.510,ABC,USD/MXN,1,OFFER,19.04274,9000000,9@15@8653948257753368229,0.0\n'`

if I only look through the data, it takes 1 minute.

```
t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
i = 0
with open(r"QuoteData.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        i+=1
print(i)
t1 = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
print(t1)

129908976
0:01:09.871744
```

But if I tried to parse the datetime, it will take 8 minutes.

```
t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
i = 0
with open(r"D:\FxQuotes\ticks.log.20170427.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        strings = line.split(",")

        datetime.datetime(
            int(strings[0][0:4]), # %Y
            int(strings[0][4:6]), # %m
            int(strings[0][6:8]), # %d
            int(strings[1][0:2]), # %H
            int(strings[1][3:5]), # %M
            int(strings[1][6:8]), # %s
            int(strings[1][9:]), # %f
        )    

        i+=1
print(i)
t1 = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
print(t1)

129908976
0:08:13.687000
```

The `split()` takes about 1 minute, and the date parsing takes about 6 minutes. Is there anything I could do to improve this?

Comment: You could look into [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). It would allow you to split the process between several threads - as many as you'd like, actually, so watch out for cpu/mem caps.

Comment: Do you have to convert the date into an actual datetime object?

Comment: ``line[:s.index(',')]`` to get the date sting any faster? or just slice on hardcoded index if the format of each line is the same. ``line[0:8]``.

Comment: @Grimmy I need to compare the time from file to some other times to determine if the data is good to use.

Comment: Look at the dupe target. You may have to mangle the string a bit to format it for ciso8601, but it is much, much faster than the alternatives.

Comment: Trick I have used in the past: You have 1B rows you are reading at ~172mb/s. If you are IO capped you can gain a lot of speed by compressing the file and read a zip stream. I got 4-8x speed boost by doing this an in addition using all the cpu cores. This was back in the days when SSDs was not mainstream yet, so it might not help.

Comment: @Grimmy I actually tried to gzip it and read gz file. It actually took much longer.

Comment: @JOHN I know it requires a bit of effort to make decompression fast in python. There are several options, but I havn't experimented with it. It will probably be slower when using a single thread.

Comment: @TemporalWolf while I agree your older question was asking something similar and the solution is basically identical, I feel that this question title is significantly different and many people won't look at a question about "durations" when they're just trying to parse a ton of dates.

Comment: See the pandas library - `import pandas as pd x = pd.read_csv('D:\FxQuotes\ticks.log.20170427.txt', header = None, parse_dates = [0,1])`

Comment: `fmt='%Y%m%d,%H:%M:%S.%f'` will parse `datetime.datetime.strptime( '20170427,20:52:01.510', fmt)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TemporalWolf had the excellent suggestion of using [ciso8601](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601). I've never heard of it so I figured I'd give it a try.

First, I benchmarked my laptop with your sample line. I made a CSV file with 10 million rows of that exact line and it took about 6 seconds to read everything. Using your date parsing code brought that up to 48 seconds which made sense because you also reported it taking 8x longer. Then I scaled the file down to 1 million rows and I could read it in 0.6 seconds and parse dates in 4.8 seconds so everything looked right.

Then I switched over to `ciso8601` and, almost like magic, the time for 1 million rows went from 4.8 seconds to about 1.9 seconds:

```
import datetime
import ciso8601

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
i = 0
with open('input.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        strings = line.split(",")
        d = ciso8601.parse_datetime('%sT%s' % (strings[0], strings[1]))
        i+=1
print(i)
t1 = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
print(t1)
```

Note that your data is *almost* in iso8601 format already. I just had to stick the date and time together with a "T" in the middle.

Comment: That ``split`` is also adding 15% to the duration. If he only want to inspect the date, we can just access ``line[0:8]``

Comment: will csv module increase speed?

Comment: it's been my experience that `"%s%s" % (str1, str2)` is one of the slower ways to concatenate strings. In fact, straight concatenation is faster in this case: `parse_datetime(strings[0] + ' ' + strings[1])`. Also, `from ciso8601 import parse_datetime` saves having to lookup the reference every call, which will be faster compared to `ciso8601.parse_datetime()` Furthermore, slicing the string (like Grimmy mentioned) cuts the time almost in half on top of any other optimization. Note these comparisons are **version dependent**.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I tried your suggestion, it works pretty well. Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `pendulum` (https://pypi.org/project/pendulum/), as it is the second fastest datetime parser and much more common/standard than `ciso8601`. See https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601#benchmark